# How does the "Implementing FP languages with fast equality, sets and maps..." technique deal with garbage collection?

Tags: hash, functional-programming, garbage-collection

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.1757&rep=rep1&type=pdf) presents a technique for the implementation of functional languages with fast equality, sets and maps, using hash-consing under the hoods. As far as my understanding goes, it uses the address of a hash-consed value as its key when inserting it on a map. This has the advantage that figuring the hashed key of essentially any value is `O(1)`, as opposed to the `O(N)` standard. What I don't understand, though, is: what happens with a map after a garbage collection? Since the GC process will cause the address of every value to change, then the configuration of the map will be incorrect. In other words, there is no guarantee that `addr(value)` will be the same for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Does the paper's section about garbage collection not answer your question?

Comment: No, that is why I asked... I understand how most methods fail, but I don't get why mark and sweep is supposed to solve this.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something really obvious since you commented that, but somehow I can't wrap my mind around it... I'll be very glad if you just say what it is!

Answer (score 2):

> Since the GC process will cause the address of every value to change

Only moving garbage collectors do that. When using non-moving algorithms like mark-and-sweep, all that happens is that unused objects are freed during the GC cycle - used objects stay exactly where they are.

Moving garbage collectors are generally seen as preferable to mark-and-sweep, but according to the abstract of the paper "mark-and-sweep becomes fast in a maximal sharing environment", which is further expanded on in section 2.4.4.

The paper also describes a way to make moving garbage collectors work (by assigning each object a unique id and using that instead of its address), but deems that impractical (section 2.4.2).